# How to use javascript in ko template in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I have a custom module which will overrride vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\shipping-method-item.html, here is the code

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<tbody collapsible="as: '$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
<tr class="row"
    click="element.selectShippingMethod">
    <td class="col col-method">
        <input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-checked="element.isSelected"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                    'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
    </td>
    <td class="col col-price">
        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.method_title" style="background-color:yellow" />
    <td class="col col-carrier"
        attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.carrier_title" />
    <!-- Column with collapsible trigger  -->
    <td class="col">
        <a toggleCollapsible="'$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Info'"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Row for shipping method description -->
<!-- ko if: method.method_code=="come_to_collect" -->
<tr class="row" data-bind="visible: MyChoiceValue() == 'True'" visible="$context['$collapsible_' + method.method_code].opened">

    <td class="col" colspan="5" i18n="'Some description.'">
        <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(method.method_code)"></div>    
            <div id="pick_up_name">
                <strong><?php echo __('Pick_up_name') ?></strong>
                <span class="price"><input type="text" name="pick_up_name"></span>
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->

<tr class="row row-error"
    if="method.error_message">
    <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
        <div role="alert" class="message error">
            <div text="method.error_message"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="no-display">
            <input type="radio"
                   attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage',
        'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        alert('abc');
    });
</script>
```

I want to add some javascript in above page but not successfull, anyone how to do that?

Comment: What's `a custom plugin`?

Comment: custom module   ..

Comment: i can't use javascript in this html even simple alert('abc');

Comment: why not add the js outside of the ko template, such as a `phtml` file?

Comment: @subroutines how and where?

Comment: I have tried before but whole checkout  structured using KO  so i am unable to use javascript there.


So i have override there respective js and make changes in there js file directly

Comment: @RutveeSojitra which js file you override?

Comment: I want to add notice under state filed on checkout page so i have change this using  vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\address-converter.js

Comment: You cannot use JS in the template file.
The proper way is to extend the js UI component of the template, add your js code there and replace the original  UI  component with yours in `requirejs-config.js`.

Comment: @MilindSingh what is the right js file i need to rewrite?